# Pass a variable to a function with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a list automatically from a JSON with the following code

```
dataObject.forEach(newList);

function newList(item, index) {
  var s = item.time;
  alert(s);
  var list = $('<li onclick="myFunction(s)">' + listItemString + '</li>');
....
}
```

The `alert(s)` print the right values of `s` but when I click on the element I get an error `ReferenceError: s is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

You have to append the variable `s`

```
function newList(item, index) {
  var s = item.time;
  var list = $('<li onclick="myFunction(\'' + s + '\')">' + listItemString + '</li>');
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
var list = $('<li>' + listItemString + '</li>');
list.on('click', function {
    myFunction(s);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var list = $('<li onclick="myFunction(this)">' + listItemString + '</li>');
```

Then you can access item.time inside myFunction